# Regarding those $\mathbb{Z}$-modules whose every finite subset generates a finite submodule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, terminology, abelian-groups

Let $X$ denote a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (aka an abelian group). Then $X$ may or may not satisfy:

> $(*)$ for all finite sets $F \subseteq X$, the module generated by $F$ is finite.

This properly generalizes the property of having finite cardinality: for instance, $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite $\mathbb{Z}$-module satisfying $(*)$. Note also that every such $\mathbb{Z}$-module must be a torsion module over the integers.

> **Questions.**
>
> - Are any interesting characterizations of $(*)$ known?
> - Does it have a name?

Comment: What are you calling "finite" here ? It can't be "finitely generated" so I'm not sure I see what the definition should be.

Comment: @CaptainLama, I'm referring to cardinality. I've edited to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: Remark: it seems possible that these are just the torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. I need to think about this some more.

Comment: Your example clearly does not seem to satisfy the property, which simply seems to be that all elements are torsion.

Comment: If the question is "for which abelian groups is every finitely generated subgroup finite" then yes it means being a torsion module. But $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ does not satisy this.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, thank you! I thought something looked weird....

Comment: To answer your second question: this property is called being "locally finite".

Comment: @Nick often that term means that finite subsets generate finite dimensional things, or possibly things that are finitely generated over some smaller base ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is equivalent to being a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

If $X$ is a torsion module, then any finitely generated submodule is a finitely generated torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module : by the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PID, it's finite.

If $X$ is not a torsion module, then any non-torsion element generates an infinite submodule (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z})$.